# Bootstrap CSS - Mobile Menu 100% in height not working on Android

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap menu with 4 menu items. Each of those items has drop-down menus. I was able to get the menu to become 100% height by doing the following:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  height: 100vh;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position:relative;
}
```

However, on an Android mobile device, this doesn't work - if you scroll down it gets cut off and if you go to scroll up it also gets cut off. Can anybody help? How do I get my Bootstrap mobile menu to be 100% in height and correctly scrollable on all mobile platforms?

Here is the dropdown menu's code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-communities" role="menu">
            <div class="row current-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="current-communities-hr" />
            <div class="row upcoming-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after looking the website it seems to me that OP problem is not with navbar taking 100% height, but with submenus gliching.

**Glitching solution 1**
The reason of glitching is actually the bootstrap `.row` rules `margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;` probably conflicting with some overflow rules. So the easy fix should be:

```
.dropdown-communities .row{
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

**Glitching solution 2:**

```
.dropdown-communities {
    /*overflow-y: hidden; <= REMOVE THIS rule. Should solves the glitching*/
}
```

---

**To make navebar 100% height on mobile** (from my previous answer):

```
.navbar-collapse {
    height: 90vh; /* Set to lower value, because 
                     height = <total height> - <.navbar-header height> 
                     so you will not lose the last menu */
    max-height: 100vh!important; /* Or max-height: none!important;  */
}
```

Here is bootstrap CSS rules that prevent you from getting 100% height on mobile devices: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L4217-L4226

---

Let me rephrase the problem (it took some time to narrow down it to just 2 CSS rules from 6k lines of CSS see the demo code below)

- There are 2 scrolls: content page scroll and menu scroll
- When you open 1-st menu and scroll menu to the bottom the sub-menus stay invisible until you scroll the main content page scroll.
- The moment you reach the bottom of the page (or scroll page content) it becomes visible.
- But when you scroll up the first part is invisible.

  You don't need to scroll to the bottom, you just need to scroll the content of the page to force redraw and make submenu visible.

Here is problem demonstration:

[image]

Source code to play with... (**check on mobile or in chrome Ctrl+ Shift + M**)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("open")
            }, function () {
                $(this).removeClass("open")
            })
        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .navbar-collapse {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .dropdown-communities {
            overflow-y: hidden
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
                       aria-expanded="true">
                        SECTION 1
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-communities" role="menu">
                        <div class="row current-communities">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4>SUB-SECTION 1</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4>SUB-SECTION 2</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4>SUB-SECTION 3</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr class="current-communities-hr">

                        <div class="row upcoming-communities">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4>HEADER 1</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4>HEADER 2</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h4>HEADER 3</h4>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        SECTION 2
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        SECTION 3
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        SECTION 4
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div style="height: 100px">Content 1</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 2</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 3</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 4</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 5</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 6</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 7</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 8</div>
<div style="height: 100px">Content 9</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This solution did not work for my website....can I send you a message with the URL and you can take a look?

Comment: @user979331 sure, can send it to my mail varren @ gmail if you don't want to show it here or just post some demo here/github so everyone can see

Comment: great! I just emailed you the URL

Comment: @user979331 updated the answer, and btw you can check the bug in google chrome, no need for android device, use `Ctrl+ Shift + M` Toggle device toolbar. I'm able to recreate the problem there

Answer (score 1):

I checked for the issue here and found that there is a `max-height` value for `.navbar-collapse` like:

```
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 340px;
}
```

This is the issue preventing menu to fit the height of view port. Following code will help you to override this rule.

```
.navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: none!important;
}
```

Make sure to use `!important` since there this rule has different values in mediaqueries.

https://jsfiddle.net/gyz357fL/

If you still have issues, please let me see your url and will check for the specific issue.